# Output is always in +ve value not the -ve for floating point values

Tags: c

i don't know if some body asked this question before or not, but here is mine:
if i have following code; what the value of total will be?
Because the output is always in +ve value not the -ve, or please guide me where i am wrong.Thankyou.
P.S: Iam using Turbo C 3.o compiler.

```
void subtract (void)
        {
            float f1;
            float f2=0.0;
            float f3=0.0;
            float total;
            printf("Enter numbers to be subtract:'q' to quit.\n ");
            while (scanf("%f",&f1)==1)
                {
                    f3=f1+f2;
                    total=f3-f1;
                    printf("Enter another # to be subtract:'q' to quit.\n ");
                    scanf("%1.0f",&f1);
                }
            printf("Subtraction Total = %1.0f",total);
            getch();
        }
```

//I am using now for simple subtraction like 3.6-9.2, i am not getting -5.6 instead I am getting 9 (This for Example)

### I done it what i just want by do the following; Thank you all

```
void subtract (void)
            {
                float f1;
                float f2;
                int status1,status2;
                float total;

                printf("Enter first number to subtract:'n' to quit.\n ");
                status1=scanf("%f",&f1);
                printf("Enter second number to be subtract from first:'n' to quit.\n ");
                status2=scanf("%f",&f2);
                while (status1==1 && status2==1)
                    {

                        total = f1 - f2;
                        printf("total=%1.2f \n",total);
                        printf("Enter first number to subtract:'n' to quit.\n ");
                        status1=scanf("%f",&f1);
                        printf("Enter second number to be subtract from first:'q' to quit.\n ");
                        status2=scanf("%f",&f2);
                    }
                printf("Subtraction Total = %1.1f",total);
                getch();
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean `+ve`? Positive exponent notation?

Comment: @Cicada I am using now for simple subtraction like 3.6-9.2, i am not getting -5.6 instead I am getting 9 (This for Example)

Comment: @Cicada +ve = positive; -ve = negative. I've seen that around all the time! Perhaps it's shorthand only cpmmon in some countries?

Comment: @deanWombourne Oh, thanks for the explanation. I've never seen this abbreviation used here in France, even when writing in English. I do lack experience though (:

Comment: @Cicada Iam sorry for using short hand.

Comment: @AbdulAziz If you've solved your problem, put it as an answer and mark it as accepted. There's nothing wrong with answering your own question :)

Comment: @deanWombourne Thanks for the advice. I am really newbie to programming as well as to stackoverflow :)

Comment: That's OK, don't worry about it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done it what i just want by do the following; Thank you all

void subtract (void)
            {
                float f1;
                float f2;
                int status1,status2;
                float total;

```
            printf("Enter first number to subtract:'n' to quit.\n ");
            status1=scanf("%f",&f1);
            printf("Enter second number to be subtract from first:'n' to quit.\n ");
            status2=scanf("%f",&f2);
            while (status1==1 && status2==1)
                {

                    total = f1 - f2;
                    printf("total=%1.2f \n",total);
                    printf("Enter first number to subtract:'n' to quit.\n ");
                    status1=scanf("%f",&f1);
                    printf("Enter second number to be subtract from first:'q' to quit.\n ");
                    status2=scanf("%f",&f2);
                }
            printf("Subtraction Total = %1.1f",total);
            getch();
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

There are too many problem to list them all. However, here are some to get your started:

1. `f2` is never set to anything other than zero.
2. You call `scanf()` twice per loop iteration, both trying to read into the same variable.
3. Each loop iteration overwrites the previous iteration's results.
4. You might want to tweak that format specifier used in the final `printf()`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but please guide me more specifically. I am a newbie in C. And you are right it does not what i have mentioned, sorry but instead it print the value of nothing :(